# GUI won't open on rapsberry pi, Vnc viewer

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am trying to run bitcoin core on a raspberry pi. Through vnc viewer.  When I try to run bitcoin-qt I get

Qt.qpa.xcb: xkeyboard extension not present on the x server
X11 connection broke error 4, did x11 server die?

I'm pretty new at all this, any advice to move forward?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution to offer but maybe the following will help you move forward?

> any advice to move forward?

Assuming the Pi is running Raspbian with X11 installed, I would try ...

- Connect a screen to the Pi using the HDMI connector, connect a USB keyboard and see if the program runs OK locally on the Pi.
- Install an X11 server (the nomenclature may seem backwards here) on a Windows PC (or Mac etc) such as Xming and see if it runs xclock ok then see if it runs bitcoin-qt
- Check that VNC can run other X11 apps OK (e.g. xclock etc). Publish details of the VNC/network etc configuration here (or maybe in superuser.com) to get better advice.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://answers.ros.org/question/350143/ros-via-vnc-xkeyboard-extension-not-present/

> I got through this issue by lots of googling. I use this set of
> instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/communit... but **instead of**
> installing:
> sudo apt install tightvncserver
>
> I used
>
> `sudo apt-get install tigervnc-standalone-server` Which solves the
> immediate problem. I can run ROS, various qt utilities, and turtlesim
> pretty well. However, getting rviz and gazebo running breaks. I dont
> know if it's simply matter of performance of the particular node I
> have on digital ocean or something more fundamental with the
> configuration.